# How is it possible to save two data in the same memory location on C?

Tags: c

I'm learning C language, specifically pointers and I have this little question.

How is it possible to save two data in the same memory location on C? Look my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    const int y = 2;
    int *const ptr_y = &y;

    *ptr_y = 4;
    
    //Values
    printf("%d\n", y);
    printf("%d\n\n", *ptr_y);

    //Memory locations
    printf("%p\n", &y);
    printf("%p\n", ptr_y);

    return (0);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
4

0x7ffeeb501788
0x7ffeeb501788
```

OUTPUT I EXPECT:

```
4 
4 

0x7ffeeb501788 
0x7ffeeb501788
```

I would like to know how this code works internally.

IMPORTANT: I am aware that the constant pointer is not correctly declared (const int *ptr_y).

Comment: It's *not* possible. What you experience is *undefined behavior* as you try to modify a constant value.

Comment: As an explanation, the compiler probably uses optimization to insert the initialized value `2` whenever `y` is used (because the compiler know that's the value of `y` and it can't be modified). You better look at the generated assembler code to see what really happen.

Comment: What leads you to believe two different values are being stored in the same memory location?  Please post the output from your program.

Comment: As you have undefined behavior, any expectation is wrong. It can seemingly work, seem to have two different values in a single memory location, set fire to your computer or summon [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Or just a plain boring crash.

Comment: In some scenarios (e.g. [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler)), you *will* see 4 4 ... (plus hopefully a compiler warning).

Comment: You tell your compiler, that `y` is 2. And it is not `volatile`. Why should the compiler bother to actually read the value from memory if the value is known? You may try to cheat your compiler. Don't expect too much from it.

Comment: My compiler refuses to compile this because I have it report warning and treat warnings like errors. You should too.

Comment: @edw4rd you can remove the `const` qualifiers, they have no influence on the question and would avoid the parallel discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `int *const ptr_y = &y;` isn't valid C, so if your compiler made an executable despite this code, all bets of its behavior are off. And in case you got no messages from the compiler, it means that your compiler configuration is non-standard. See [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Strictly speaking `printf("%p\n", &y);` should also be cast to `(const void*)&y`.

---

Where `const int y = 2;` stores the value 2 isn't specified by the C standard. It could be in a register, on the stack, in read/write memory labelled "read only" (`.rodata` or similar) or it could be stored in true read-only memory like flash, in case of embedded systems.

If you do a write access to that memory location, the behavior isn't defined by the C standard. [Undefined behavior](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) = anything could happen, including:

- it could update the memory and next time you read back a `4`.
- it could update the memory but the compiler optimizer doesn't generate code to read it back so you still get `2`.
- the compiler could ignore to generate code for the write attempt.
- it could be true read-only memory so when you attempt to write to it, nothing happens.
- it could be true read-only memory and protected, so that a write attempt results in a hardware exception or similar.

Overall, it isn't overly meaningful to analyse what exactly happened (symptoms) when you invoke undefined behavior. What's important is to understand *why* the code contains undefined behavior (root cause).

Answer (score 2):

The code invokes [undefined behavior](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3) because you cannot change the contents of a `const` variable, for that reason the output has no meaning, it can be anything as per the definition of undefined behavior linked above.

You are not saving the data in two different locations, it's the same location.

`y` is stored in some (memory) location, that location has an address, `ptr_y` is a pointer and it contains that same memory address because you assigned it using `address-of` operator `&`:

```
int *const ptr_y = &y;
```

The above assignment discards the `const` qualifier and as such, you are then allowed by the compiler to try and change the value of `y` with `*ptr_y = 4`, this is still invalid but because of the faulty assignment it becomes possible. You should always respect the `const` qualifiers in pointers, if you used:

```
const int y = 2;
const int* ptr_y = &y;
```

The compiler would not have let you do it:

```
*ptr_y = 4;
```

> *error: assignment of read-only location* '**ptr_y'*

With correct code, by dereferencing `ptr_y` using `*` operator you are accessing the address stored in `ptr_y` which incidentally is the address of `y`, so it's the same memory address, you are just accessing it in two different ways:

```
int y = 2; // non const

int *const ptr_y = &y; // constant pointer is allowed

*ptr_y = 4;

//Values
printf("%d\n", y);
printf("%d\n\n", *ptr_y);

//Memory locations
printf("%p\n", (void*)&y); // %p specifier expects void*
printf("%p\n", (void*)ptr_y);
```

```
4
4

0x7ffd0f9aee34
0x7ffd0f9aee34
```